# Debugging NPOI NuGet code

Tags: .net, debugging, nuget, npoi

I am working on a project in which I use [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) v2.3.1 NuGet package. While debugging my code, I see the following messages in output without an actual exception being thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'NPOI.OpenXml4Net.Exceptions.InvalidFormatException' in NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll

Since I can't step into the code, I downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/) of NPOI and struggled to get it configured for debugging with little success and a lot of wasted time. Is there a way to debug the code the NuGet package directly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the source code and produce a debug version DLL, then reference these DLLs from your own project.

Make sure all PDB files are also presented in same folder. So you can step into (F11) target source code from the breakpoint in your project.